# React.memo reset state to previous

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memo

I have a table with rows, and every row has an action button that updates that row.

When I don't use React.memo, everything works fine. If I put rows component into React.memo, on the first update it is ok, but next one updates the current row, while previous returns to the initial state.

I am using reducer to update state, and when I console.log state it updates as expected. But when I click on the action button from the next row, as a starting point it uses the previous state, and then returns previous row to initial value.

It seems as if action button from the next row keeps the reference to previous state as it was not re-rendered.

Here are the main parts of the code:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    ....
        case 'update':
            return { ...state, result: action.payload };
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown state action");
    }
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { loading: initialLoading, result: null });

const result = state.result;
const loading = state.loading;

// Called from the row action button
const handleUpdateResult = React.useCallback(index => data => {
      // When called from the next row action button - result keeps old state, even component rendered row with new values
      const newConnection = {
          ...result.connections[index],
          status: data.status
      };

      const newConnections = [...result.connections.slice(0, index), newConnection, ...result.connections.slice(index + 1)];
      const updatedResult = { ...result, connections: newConnections };

      setResult(updatedResult);
}, [result, setResult]);


const setResult = useCallback((newState) => {
    dispatch({ type: "update", payload: newState });
}, []);
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong :/...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will have the same situation, so I will explain the issue and the solution.

The problem is that `handleUpdateResult` is using the current state. Somewhere in documentation I read that whenever you update the state and you need the current state for that, use reducer. I am actually using reducer, but still I used the current state in the function `handleUpdateResult` which make a small mess :).

Anyway, instead of using the state there, I send an action to reducer to update the value, and everything works fine:

```
// Called from the row action button
const handleUpdateResult = React.useCallback((index, newStatus) => row => {
      const newRow = {
          ...row,
          status: newStatus
      };

      setResult({
          action: "updateRow",
          payload: {
              index: index,
              row: newRow
          }
      });
}, [setResult]);
```

When `result` state is removed from the function, and current state is used from the reducer, everything works fine. The logic to update row is moved to reducer.